# OpenMP custom reduction variable

Tags: c, openmp

I've been assigned to implement the idea of a reduction variable without using the reduction clause. I set up this basic code to test it.

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    val += 1;
}
sum += val;
```

so at the end `sum == n`.

Each thread should set val as a private variable, and then the addition to sum should be a critical section where the threads converge, e.g.

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, val) shared(n) num_threads(nthreads)
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    val += 1;
}
#pragma omp critical
{
    sum += val;
}
```

I can't figure out how to maintain the private instance of val for the critical section. I have tried surrounding the whole thing in a larger pragma, e.g.

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel private(val) shared(sum)
{
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(n) num_threads(nthreads)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        val += 1;
    }
#pragma omp critical
    {
        sum += val;
    }
}
```

but I don't get the correct answer. How should I set up the pragmas and clauses to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about this syntax. Is it supposed to create several `val`s for the different threads? I doubt it and that would mean that `val` is accessed and written to by different threads at the same time

Comment: I would suggest using an array with size `nthreads` and add to `array[omp_get_thread_num()]`, afterwards, calculating the total of the values in the array. It's much more obvious ;-)

Comment: Yes, there are much more practical ways to do this but that isn't the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are pretty much flaws in your program. Lets look at each program (flaws are written as comments).

Program one

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, val) shared(n) num_threads(nthreads)
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    val += 1;
}
// At end of this, all the openmp threads die. 
// The reason is the "pragma omp parallel" creates threads, 
// and the scope of those threads were till the end of that for loop. So, the thread dies
// So, there is only one thread (i.e. the main thread) that will enter the critical section
#pragma omp critical
{
    sum += val;
}
```

Program two

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel private(val) shared(sum)
 // pragma omp parallel creates the threads
{
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(n) num_threads(nthreads)
  // There is no need to create another set of threads
  // Note that "pragma omp parallel" always creates threads.
  // Now you have created nested threads which is wrong
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        val += 1;
    }
#pragma omp critical
    {
        sum += val;
    }
}
```

The best solution would be

```
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
int nThreads = 5;
#pragma omp parallel shared(sum, n) num_threads(nThreads) // Create omp threads, and always declare the shared and private variables here.
// Also declare the maximum number of threads.
// Do note that num_threads(nThreads) doesn't guarantees that the number of omp threads created is nThreads. It just says that maximum number of threads that can be created is nThreads... 
// num_threads actually limits the number of threads that can be created
{
    double val = 0.0;  // val can be declared as local variable (for each thread) 
#pragma omp for nowait       // now pragma for  (here you don't need to create threads, that's why no "omp parallel" )
    // nowait specifies that the threads don't need to wait (for other threads to complete) after for loop, the threads can go ahead and execute the critical section 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        val += 1;
    }
#pragma omp critical
    {
        sum += val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that nested parallel regions cause new thread teams to be spawned only if nested parallelism is explicitly enabled which it is _not by default_ per the OpenMP specification.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to explicitly specify shared variables in OpenMP as variables from outer scopes are always shared by default (unless `default(none)` clause is specified). As `private` variables have undefined initial values, you should zero the private copy before the accumulation loop. Loop counters are automatically recognised and made private - no need to explicitly declare them as such. Also since you are simply updating a value, you should use an `atomic` construct as it is more lightweight than the full critical section.

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100000000;
double sum = 0.0;
double val = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel private(val)
{
    val = 0.0;
    #pragma omp for num_threads(nthreads)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        val += 1;
    }
    #pragma omp atomic update
    sum += val;
}
```

The `update` clause was added to the `atomic` construct in OpenMP 3.1 so if your compiler conforms to an earlier OpenMP version (e.g. if you use MSVC++ which only supports OpenMP 2.0 even in VS2012) you would have to remove the `update` clause. As `val` is not used outside the parallel loop, it could be declared in the inner scope as in the answer of veda and then it automatically becomes a private variable.

Note that `parallel for` is a shortcut for nesting two OpenMP constructs: `parallel` and `for`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for sharing_clauses scheduling_clauses
for (...) {
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
#pragma omp parallel sharing_clauses
#pragma omp for scheduling_clauses
for (...) {
}
```

This is also true for the other two combined constructs: `parallel sections` and `parallel workshare` (Fortran only)