# How can I use the openmp to parallelize my aggregation code?

Tags: c++, openmp, aggregate-functions, aggregate

Actually,I want to do an aggregation on the table,every column of which is an array.so I need to scan the table and do the aggregation.But Openmp seem doesn't support that using array name after the reduction directive.So,How can I use the openmp to parallelize my aggregation code?thx

Comment: Am I getting you right, you want to get a sum of the column?

Comment: Get the sum of one column , I can used the this : reduction(+:sum),but in my code ,there are 8 column and I need to get the sum of column according to two column of the 8 column. According to the value of the two column ,I have a var - hashtable[2][3].this hashtable store the sum of different situation(which is actually just 6 situation) of the two column.

Comment: Could you provide unparalleled code? Have you already tried something?

Comment: int i;
     for( i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        if(p_shipdate[i] <= hi_date){
         Entry.count_order++;
         Entry.sum_qty  +=  p_quantity[i];
         Entry.sum_disc +=  p_discount[i];
         Entry.sum_base_price += p_extendedprice[i];
         Entry.sum_disc_price+=(p_extendedprice[i]*=(1- p_discount[i]));
         Entry.sum_charge +=p_extendedprice[i]*(1 - p_tax[i]);
        }
     } if you know TPCH,this is Query1 of it,but the data is column orient

Comment: #define Entry hashtable[p_linestatus[i]][p_returnflag[i]],linestatus and returnflag are the two column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are facing 2 separate limitations in OpenMP that prevent you from doing your thing:

1. Your sum accumulator variable isn't a simple variable, but an array entry that you would like to pass to OpenMP ["by name"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name). OpenMP doesn't support that. Get the value from the array, write it into a local variable, do the reduction on the local variable and write the value back to the array afterwards.
2. "Entry" has a user-defined data type. OpenMP doesn't support reduction over those either. So all the 6 members of "Entry" that you want to sum up have to become separate local variables. You can pass a list of the 6 variables to the OpenMP "reduction" clause.

Comment: thank for your answer,Are you mean that the only way I can do this is to declare some other counterpart variable of the var in the struct array.this mean that if I have a "struct aggr_t{long a,double b,double c} hash table[2][3]",I should redeclare 24 var to use reduction directive? Is there another way not seems clumsy?thx

Comment: Hmmm, I hadn't seen that your macro "Entry" contains a reference to the loop variable "i". This complicates things further, you are right, you'd need many, many local variables. So if you don't want to do that, I'd say you have 2 options: 1.) Don't use any reduction, but instead let all threads work on the same shared data, which means you'll need synchronization to avoid lost updates, which will probably kill your speedup. 2.) Write your own reduction code.

Comment: Additional information for option 2: Create a long spanning "parallel" pragma, inside that you have 3 parts: A. create a copy of the original hashtable for every thread, B. then create an "omp for" loop (still within the outer parallel pragma) in which every thread works only on its local copy, C. then after that (still within the outer parallel pragma) do the reduction using synchronization. You can find an example of the general structure here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754485/openmp-custom-reduction-variable